# User that can only logon with ssh keys, not password

Tags: ssh, login

I'm trying to create a user on a Linux box that can only log on via ssh with a key specified in authorized_keys. The user should not be able to log on via password, neither via ssh nor locally at the console. How would I do this?

Currently I do:

```
useradd -m myuser
passwd myuser
vi /etc/shadow
```

and replace the password field with '*'. There must be a better way? If I don't set the passwd first, ssh won't work either saying in the log "User myuser not allowed because account is locked"

Comment: Hey! there are plenty of sites that describe how to do that. f.e here:http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/ The other thing you need to do is disable password login in ssh config. The instructions are here: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-to-disable-password-authentication-for-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passwd -l myuser` will effectively disable user password

Comment: Didn't know about that flag. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a password and don't tell them what it is.

Comment: Never mind the user; the machine is on the public internet, and I simply don't want the possibility of anybody logging on without ssh keys which are stronger than any password.

Comment: @JohannesErnst If you use `head -c57 /dev/urandom | base64` to generate the password, then nobody is going to guess that password.